# Find the number of occurrence of each element in an array and update the information related to each elements

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have a big 2-D array, `array[length][2]`. the `length= 500000`.

In `array[i][0]= hex number`,  `array[i][1]= 0` or `1`, which represents some information related to each hex number. Like this:

```
array[i][0]    array[i][1]

e05f56f8           1

e045ac44           1

e05f57fc           1

e05f57b4           1

e05ff8dc           0

e05ff8ec           0

e05ff900           1
```

I want to get a new array which stores: the hex number,# of occurance, the sum of array[i][1] of the same hex number.

I write the code like this:

```
//First Sort the array according to array[][0]

int x,y,temp1,temp2;
  for (x=lines_num1-2;x>=0;x--)
    {
      for (y=0;y<=x;y++)
       {
        if(array[y][0]>array[y+1][0])
         {
            temp1=array[y][0];
            array[y][0]=array[y+1][0];
            array[y+1][0]=temp1;

            temp2=array[y][1];
            array[y][1]=array[y+1][1];
            array[y+1][1]=temp2;                
          }
       }
   }

// generate the new_array[][]
int new_array[length][3];
int n=0;
for (n=0; n<length; n++){
   new_array[n][0]=0;
   new_array[n][1]=0;
   new_array[n][2]=0;
}
int prev = array[0][0];
new_array[0][0]=array[0][0];
new_array[0][1]=1;
new_array[0][2]=array[0][2];
for (k=1;k<length;k++)
  {
     if (array[k][0] == prev)
       {
         new_array[n][1]=new_array[n][1]+1;
         new_array[n][2]=new_array[n][2]+array[k][0];
       }else{
         prev = array[k][0];
         new_array[n+1][0]=array[k][0];
         new_array[n+1][1]=new_array[n+1][1]+1;
         new_array[n+1][2]=new_array[n+1][2]+array[k][0];
         n++;
       }
   }
```

But the code seems not work as I expected. First the sorting is so slow. And It seems cannot generate the correct new_array. Any suggestion on how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would write a hash function to index the result array with the hexadecimal value directly. Then it is simple:

```
struct {
    unsigned int nocc;
    unsigned int nsum;
} result[/* ... */];

/* calculate the results */
for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i) {
    int *curr = &array[i];
    unsigned int index = hash(curr[0]);    

    result[index].nocc++;
    result[index].nsum += curr[1];
}
```

If you want to sort your array, don't reinventing the wheel: use `qsort` from the standard C library.

Comment: what does result[/* ... */] mean?

Comment: Is hash a lib function from C? Or I need to write a hash function myself?

Comment: You need to write one yourself. It depends on what your goals are (collisions, etc.). And the comments indicates the size of the `result` array.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is slow because you're using bubble sort to sort the data. Bubble sort has quadratic average complexity, which means it has to perform more then 100 billion comparisons and swaps to sort your array. For this reason, [never use bubble sort](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/bubble/bubble.html). Instead, learn to use the [`qsort`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) library function and apply it to your problem.

Also, your sorting code has at least one bug: when exchanging values for the second column of the array, you are getting the value with the wrong column index, `[3]` instead of `[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario insertion sort is the right solution, while doing the insertion itself you could make the #count and the sum. When the sort is finished, you will have your result array as well.

The code might look something like this

```
int hex = 0, count = 0, sum = 0, iHole;
for (i=1; i < lines_num1 -1; i++)
{
     hex = array[i][0];
     count = array[i][1];
     sum = array[i][2];

     iHole = i
     // keep moving the hole to next smaller index until A[iHole - 1] is <= item
     while (iHole > 0 and array[iHole - 1][0] > hex)
       {
         // move hole to next smaller index
         A[iHole][0] = A[iHole - 1][0];
         A[iHole][1] = A[iHole - 1][1];
         A[iHole][2] = A[iHole - 1][2];
         iHole = iHole - 1
       }
     // put item in the hole
      if (array[iHole][0] == hex) 
      {
        array[iHole][1]++;
        array[iHole][2] += array[iHole][0];
       }
      else 
      {
        array[iHole][0]  = hex;
        array[iHole][1]  = 1;
        array[iHole][2]  = hex;
      }

   }
```

So the cost of making the second array is cost of the sorting itself. O(n) best case, O(n^2) worst case, and you don't have to travel again to make the sum and count.

Remember this sort is a inplace sort. If you don't want to affect your original array that could be done as well with iHole pointing to the new array. The iHole should point to the tail of new array instead of "i"